# rails 4.0.1 can't show ruby code in view via javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, escaping

I'm trying to update vote count via ajax once user has voted. My code works fine except for something which should be pretty basic, which is showing the new total number of votes.

My javascript has the following code:

```
    var voteCount = "<%= @trip.total_up_votes %>";
    ...
    $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function() {
            console.log("SAVED TO VOTES TABLE SUCCESSFULLY");
            $('#voting_up').html(voteCount);
        },
    ...
    });
```

Once the vote link has been clicked, everything gets added to the table fine except it shows the new vote count as <%= @trip.total_up_votes %> i.e. as a string. The total_up_votes method simply counts the number of up votes from the votes table. This works fine when the page is first loaded or when it's refreshed.

I've tried escape_javascript and many other suggestions after trawling through the internet but I'm still stuck. Could someone help please?

EDIT:
As requested, my votes_controller does this:

```
    def cast_vote()
        @vote = Vote.where("user_id = ? AND trip_id = ?", current_user, params[:id]).first || Vote.new(:user_id => current_user)  
        @vote.vote_type = params[:vote_type]
        @vote.user_id = params[:user_id]
        @vote.trip_id = params[:id]

        respond_to do |format|
           @vote.save
           format.html {redirect_to :back}
           format.js
        end
    end
```

Comment: Please share your controller method.

Comment: Is this javascript in its own file, or embedded in a script tag in the html.erb file?

Comment: it's in its own  .js file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dropping the quotes?

```
var voteCount = <%= @trip.total_up_votes %>;
...
$.ajax({
...
success: function() {
        console.log("SAVED TO VOTES TABLE SUCCESSFULLY");
        $('#voting_up').html(voteCount);
    },
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all overkill.  You should use the ruby ajax helper "remote".  use this:

```
<%= link_to "Vote up", vote_up_path, remote: true %>
```

The remote: true above will tell the browser to handle the link via ajax, so the page will not get reloaded.  vote_up_path is just an example.  Lets say vote_up_path takes you to the controller action votes#upvote, then in your votes views folder you should have a file called upvote.js.erb.  In that file, have the following code:

```
var voteCount = <%= @trip.total_up_votes %>;
console.log("SAVED TO VOTES TABLE SUCCESSFULLY");
$('#voting_up').html(voteCount);
```

Comment: Fair enough but I kinda want to know why my code doesn't work first.